# Does the Resize Images Firebase extension only resize, or does it compress the output images also?

Tags: firebase, image-resizing, firebase-extensions

Essentially, I'm trying to learn whether or not the extension automatically optimizes the output images, similar to what [Tinypng](https://tinypng.com/) or [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/transformation_reference#q_quality) does?

Sorry if it seems obvious, but I searched the extension's [landing page description](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-storage-resize-images) and related [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions) and neither says anything about image compression or optimization, one way or another.

It seems intuitive that Firebase would optimize the output image, but if they in fact do, it's surprising that they would be silent about it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can see exactly what it does by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/storage-resize-images).  BTW your second question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  I suggest removing it in order to prevent your post from being deleted.  If you want to give feedback to someone at Firebase, [contact support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact).

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson I re-worded from a question to a statement. I checked the source code and could not find anything I (as a novice) was able to decipher as compression - hopefully someone with definitive knowledge will respond.